# Add all classes to Intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Is there a way that I can add all the classes in my solution to IntelliSense? By default my IntelliSense only shows suggestions for imported types.

E.g. it will only suggest `Guid` if I specify `using system;` in the file I am working on.

Comment: Hi,what the type of your project? Was it an old project? Did you create a new solution to test whether it is work? l have tested a new net core web application and add some classes in it and  it works well. Besides, please delete .vs folder to check whether it can help you. Or if you change some settings causing this behavior，please try `Options-->Import and Export Settings-->Reset all settings`.

Comment: It's a .NET 4.7 project C#. Are you saying it is default behavior for Intellisense to show all classes? I have since downloaded an extension that gives me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an extension that does this. [IntelliSense Extender 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntelliSenseExtender). It provides IntelliSense completions not only for imported types, but for all available in current solution and referenced assemblies. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Wouter, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)